# RSpec database cleaner not happening between tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, database-cleaner

I have a rather complex series of tests, reproduced in much simpler form below:

```
# Credit cards that should succeed; totally opening to other ways of running this loop, if it's what's causing the error! It's just the only thing I thought of to be DRY
["2134", "1234"].each do |card|
  describe "enter card number", job: true do
    before do
      fill_in "card_number", with: card
    end

    it "should create a record" do
      Record.count.should == 1
    end
  end
end

# Credit card that should fail
# Just the one number here
  describe "enter card number" do
    before do
      fill_in "card_number", with: "5678"
    end

    it "should create a record" do
      Record.count.should == 0
    end
  end
```

In the config I needed to turn off `use_transactional_fixtures` because these are javascript based tests and the transactional fixtures weren't working for me. So I tried to implement database cleaner like so (using Sucker Punch gem instructions https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch, since I also eventually need to test the gem):

```
  # Database cleaner set up below
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  # Clean up all jobs specs with truncation
  config.before(:each, job: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

The problem is that this is not helping:

- For credit cards that should succeed (with each loop), the first passes, but the subsequent all fail because the `Record.count` keeps building
- For credit card that should fail, it fails because by the time that test is run, there are already `Records` in the test db

Basically the only way it passes is with a forced clean in a `before(:all)` (neither `before` nor `after` did the trick)

```
 # Credit cards that should succeed
    ["2134", "1234"].each do |card|
      describe "enter card number", job: true do

        before(:all) do
          Record.destroy_all
        end

        before do
          # did not work to put the destroy here 
          fill_in "card_number", with: card
        end

        it "should create a record" do
          Record.count.should == 1
        end

        # did not work to put the destroy here 
        # after do
        #  Record.destroy_all
        # end
      end
    end

# Credit card that should fail
  describe "enter card number" do
    before do
      # On this one, the Record.destroy_all could have gone anywhere
      Record.destroy_all 
      fill_in "card_number", with: "5678"
    end

    it "should create a record" do
      Record.count.should == 0
    end
  end
```

How do I set up database cleaner properly? Or am I just supposed to do the `before(:all)`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, which version of `database_cleaner` are you using?

If you look at the gem's documentation, you will see something different:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
```

Also, I'm not sure if this will work as you expect it:

```
   ["2134", "1234"].each do |card|
      describe "enter card number", job: true do
        ...
      end
    end
```

I would find a different way to test those two cases. Is it really necessary to enter two numbers like that?